# Is the zero map unique?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a linear transformation $T$, from a vector space $V$ to $V’$, and this transformation is a zero map, i.e. $T(v)=0$, $\forall$ $ v \in V$, is $T$ unique? Is there any other transformation $T_o$, say, which is also a zero map?

I guess this is not possible since,
$T(v)=0=T_o(v)$
$\implies T(v)=T_o(v)$
Since $v \in V$ is arbitrary, the maps $T$ and $T_o$ are one and the same and thus the zero map must necessarily be unique. Is this the right way to prove this?

Comment: Sounds correct $\space$

Comment: Cool, thank you for verifying.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this correct. Concisely, a function $f:X\to Y$ between sets is specified uniquely by its values on the elements of $X$.

Comment: So to use this in my question, we can say that $T$ and $T_o$ are acting on the same arbitrary element $v$ of the domain $V$, and producing the same image $0 \in V’$. If it were the case that $T \neq T_o$ then we would certainly get different images.

Comment: Simply put: the zero map has $T(v)=0$ for all $v\in V$. This uniquely defines it because it specifies all of the information of a function.

Comment: @user733666 "we can say that $T$ and $T_o$ are acting on the same arbitrary element $v$ of the domain $V$ and producing the same image $0∈V′$." Exactly, and this is all you have to say. Your next sentence is actually redundant (it may temporarily help you feel more secure about your thinking but it's redundant) because the very *definition* of equality of two functions is that they are equal at every point of their domain. Explicitly, two functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ are said to be equal, written $f=g$, if for every $x\in X$, we have $f(x)=g(x)$ (this is an equality of elements of $Y$).

Comment: Yes yes. This seems like a simple thing but my understanding is better now. Thank you all.

Comment: No problem. Make sure to accept the answer if your question is resolved.